# JavaScript/jQuery - Input original value first time and previous value second times on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the value animate, but with the function that I use, the past value needs to be stored somewhere (not sure where)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="100">
<h1>My value: <span id="text-output">100</span>
```

JS

```
$input = $('#text');
    $input.on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var memoryValue = 1; //I need this to be original value first time and previous value second times

        animateNumber($('#text-output'), memoryValue, val, 300);

    })
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5Sa7/

I created a dom element that had a class and I increment the class name each time the value is changed, but that will get ugly if the value is changed multiple times.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use a global variable.

Comment: @pmandell hm... sounds good, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign to a data attribute on the element.  [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

```
$input = $('#text');
$this.data("previousVal", 100); //Initialize the data attribute to 100
$input.on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    var memoryValue = $this.data("previousVal");
    $this.data("previousVal", val);
    animateNumber($('#text-output'), memoryValue, val, 300);
})
```

Comment: I used your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5yBt8/1/ but I get one error for the first time... any idea why?

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu  probably because the input's data attribute has not been initialized.  See my edit above.

Comment: Thank for your help. Look at the final output: http://jsfiddle.net/5yBt8/9/  Any idea why the number is not the same as the desired output? (Same as the input?)